# Tomcat 7 won't start

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, java, permgen

I was running a java application and it's a lot of records i am bringing back form the database, i got a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` in the browser. Now Tomcat 7.0 wont start. The Tomcat logs showed this:

**Error Log**

```
[2013-04-29 16:23:05] [info]  Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.10.0 64-bit) started
[2013-04-29 16:23:05] [info]  Running 'Tomcat7' Service...
[2013-04-29 16:23:05] [info]  Starting service...
[2013-04-29 16:23:05] [error] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[2013-04-29 16:23:05] [error] Failed creating java C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll
[2013-04-29 16:23:05] [error] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[2013-04-29 16:23:05] [error] ServiceStart returned 1
[2013-04-29 16:23:05] [error] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[2013-04-29 16:23:05] [info]  Run service finished.
[2013-04-29 16:23:05] [info]  Commons Daemon procrun finished
```

Can some one tell me how i can fix this every time i click start on tomcat it tried to start and then fails.

**hs_err_pid4284.log**

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006818b51a, pid=4284, tid=4760
#
# JRE version: 7.0_10-b18
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.6-b04 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x1ab51a]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000056c1800):  VMThread [stack: 0x00000000061b0000,0x00000000062b0000] [id=4760]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000012cee80

Registers:
RAX=0x00000000012ceeb8, RBX=0x00000000062af320, RCX=0x00000000010f8420, RDX=0x00000000015e237c
RSP=0x00000000062af2a0, RBP=0x00000000010f3330, RSI=0x00000000010f0df0, RDI=0x00000000010f3500
R8 =0x00000000015d0000, R9 =0x0000000000000006, R10=0x00000000062af350, R11=0x00000000015e237c
R12=0x00000000010f3ea0, R13=0x000000000000000a, R14=0x00000000056590d0, R15=0x0000000000000000
RIP=0x000000006818b51a, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000062af2a0)
0x00000000062af2a0:   00000000015d5510 0000000000000000
0x00000000062af2b0:   00000000012ceeb8 00000000012cee40


Instructions: (pc=0x000000006818b51a)
0x000000006818b4fa:   cc cc cc cc cc cc 40 53 48 83 ec 20 48 8b d9 e8
0x000000006818b50a:   32 bf 0b 00 84 c0 0f 84 b7 00 00 00 48 8b 43 20
0x000000006818b51a:   48 8b 48 c8 48 81 f9 ff ff 00 00 77 0e 8b d1 48
0x000000006818b52a:   8b 48 e8 e8 ce af f3 ff 48 8b c8 80 3d 65 3c 4b 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00000000012ceeb8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000095d000
RBX=0x00000000062af320 is an unknown value
RCX=0x00000000010f8420 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00000000015e237c is an Interpreter codelet
method entry point (kind = native)  [0x00000000015e2100, 0x00000000015e2980]  2176 bytes
RSP=0x00000000062af2a0 is an unknown value
RBP=0x00000000010f3330 is an unknown value
RSI=0x00000000010f0df0 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000000010f3500 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00000000015d0000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000006 is an unknown value
R10=0x00000000062af350 is an unknown value
R11=0x00000000015e237c is an Interpreter codelet
method entry point (kind = native)  [0x00000000015e2100, 0x00000000015e2980]  2176 bytes
R12=0x00000000010f3ea0 is an unknown value
R13=0x000000000000000a is an unknown value
R14=0x00000000056590d0 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00000000061b0000,0x00000000062b0000],  sp=0x00000000062af2a0,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x1ab51a]

VM_Operation (0x000000000924f3c0): ParallelGCFailedPermanentAllocation, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x0000000007ae0800


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000000708a000 JavaThread "http-bio-8084-exec-104" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3296, stack(0x000000000d930000,0x000000000da30000)]
  0x000000000f286000 JavaThread "http-bio-8084-exec-103" daemon [_thread_blocked, 

Other Threads:
=>0x00000000056c1800 VMThread [stack: 0x00000000061b0000,0x00000000062b0000] [id=4760]
  0x0000000005784800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00000000069b0000,0x0000000006ab0000] [id=1760]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x000000000095a890] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x00000000056c1800
[0x000000000095ad90] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x0000000007ae0800
[0x000000000095b310] MethodData_lock - owner thread: 0x0000000007ae0800

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 87296K, used 0K [0x00000000faab0000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 87232K, 0% used [0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000fffe0000)
  from space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000ffff0000)
  to   space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000ffff0000,0x00000000ffff0000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 174784K, used 56171K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000faab0000, 0x00000000faab0000)
  object space 174784K, 32% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f36dac38,0x00000000faab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 83966K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 83968K, 99% used [0x00000000eae00000,0x00000000effffb40,0x00000000f0000000)

Card table byte_map: [0x00000000045d0000,0x0000000004680000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000003e79000

Polling page: 0x00000000001f0000

Code Cache  [0x00000000015d0000, 0x0000000001f00000, 0x00000000045d0000)
 total_blobs=1903 nmethods=1504 adapters=348 free_code_cache=40047Kb largest_free_block=40703552

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 3663.180 Thread 0x0000000005757800 nmethod 1674 0x0000000001d07210 code [0x0000000001d07780, 0x0000000001d0a698]
Event: 3663.322 Thread 0x0000000005757800 1675             java.lang.Class::arrayContentsEq (70 bytes)
Event: 3663.323 Thread 0x0000000005757800 nmethod 1675 0x0000000001def050 code [0x0000000001def180, 0x0000000001def258]
Event: 3663.347 Thread 0x000000000576e000 nmethod 1661 0x0000000001eda810 code [0x0000000001edba60, 0x0000000001eeb478]
Event: 3663.413 Thread 0x0000000005757800 1676             org.apache.log4j.helpers.PatternConverter::format (127 bytes)
Event: 3663.435 Thread 0x0000000005757800 nmethod 1676 0x0000000001d05510 code [0x0000000001d05780, 0x0000000001d063d8]
Event: 3663.442 Thread 0x000000000576e000 1677             org.apache.log4j.helpers.PatternParser$LiteralPatternConverter::format (10 bytes)
Event: 3663.443 Thread 0x000000000576e000 nmethod 1677 0x0000000001d05290 code [0x0000000001d053e0, 0x0000000001d05468]
Event: 3663.464 Thread 0x0000000005757800 1678   !         org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory::getBeanNamesForType (509 bytes)
Event: 3664.753 Thread 0x0000000005757800 nmethod 1678 0x0000000001e2eed0 code [0x0000000001e2f380, 0x0000000001e32718]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 4039.689 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1795 (full 850):
 PSYoungGen      total 87296K, used 0K [0x00000000faab0000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 87232K, 0% used [0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000fffe0000)
  from space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000ffff0000)
  to   space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000ffff0000,0x00000000ffff0000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 174784K, used 56171K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000faab0000, 0x00000000faab0000)
  object space 174784K, 32% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f36dac38,0x00000000faab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 83966K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 83968K, 99% used [0x00000000eae00000,0x00000000effffb40,0x00000000f0000000)
}
Event: 4039.689 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1796 (full 851):
 PSYoungGen      total 87296K, used 0K [0x00000000faab0000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 87232K, 0% used [0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000fffe0000)
  from space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000ffff0000)
  to   space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000ffff0000,0x00000000ffff0000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 174784K, used 56171K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000faab0000, 0x00000000faab0000)
  object space 174784K, 32% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f36dac38,0x00000000faab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 83966K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 83968K, 99% used [0x00000000eae00000,0x00000000effffb40,0x00000000f0000000)
Event: 4039.933 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1796 (full 851):
 PSYoungGen      total 87296K, used 0K [0x00000000faab0000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 87232K, 0% used [0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000fffe0000)
  from space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000ffff0000)
  to   space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000ffff0000,0x00000000ffff0000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 174784K, used 56171K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000faab0000, 0x00000000faab0000)
  object space 174784K, 32% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f36dac38,0x00000000faab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 83966K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 83968K, 99% used [0x00000000eae00000,0x00000000effffb40,0x00000000f0000000)
}
Event: 4039.933 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1797 (full 851):
 PSYoungGen      total 87296K, used 0K [0x00000000faab0000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 87232K, 0% used [0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000fffe0000)
  from space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000ffff0000)
  to   space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000ffff0000,0x00000000ffff0000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 174784K, used 56171K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000faab0000, 0x00000000faab0000)
  object space 174784K, 32% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f36dac38,0x00000000faab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 83966K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 83968K, 99% used [0x00000000eae00000,0x00000000effffb40,0x00000000f0000000)
Event: 4039.935 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1797 (full 851):
 PSYoungGen      total 87296K, used 0K [0x00000000faab0000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 87232K, 0% used [0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000fffe0000)
  from space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000ffff0000,0x00000000ffff0000,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000ffff0000)
 ParOldGen       total 174784K, used 56171K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000faab0000, 0x00000000faab0000)
  object space 174784K, 32% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f36dac38,0x00000000faab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 83966K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 83968K, 99% used [0x00000000eae00000,0x00000000effffb40,0x00000000f0000000)
}
Event: 4039.935 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1798 (full 852):
 PSYoungGen      total 87296K, used 0K [0x00000000faab0000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 87232K, 0% used [0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000fffe0000)
  from space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000ffff0000,0x00000000ffff0000,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000ffff0000)
 ParOldGen       total 174784K, used 56171K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000faab0000, 0x00000000faab0000)
  object space 174784K, 32% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f36dac38,0x00000000faab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 83966K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 83968K, 99% used [0x00000000eae00000,0x00000000effffb40,0x00000000f0000000)
Event: 4040.227 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1798 (full 852):
 PSYoungGen      total 87296K, used 0K [0x00000000faab0000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 87232K, 0% used [0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000fffe0000)
  from space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000ffff0000,0x00000000ffff0000,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000ffff0000)
 ParOldGen       total 174784K, used 56171K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000faab0000, 0x00000000faab0000)
  object space 174784K, 32% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f36dac38,0x00000000faab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 83966K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 83968K, 99% used [0x00000000eae00000,0x00000000effffb40,0x00000000f0000000)
}
Event: 4040.229 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1799 (full 852):
 PSYoungGen      total 87296K, used 0K [0x00000000faab0000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 87232K, 0% used [0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000fffe0000)
  from space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000ffff0000,0x00000000ffff0000,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000ffff0000)
 ParOldGen       total 174784K, used 56171K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000faab0000, 0x00000000faab0000)
  object space 174784K, 32% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f36dac38,0x00000000faab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 83966K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 83968K, 99% used [0x00000000eae00000,0x00000000effffb40,0x00000000f0000000)
Event: 4040.232 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1799 (full 852):
 PSYoungGen      total 87296K, used 0K [0x00000000faab0000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 87232K, 0% used [0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000fffe0000)
  from space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000ffff0000)
  to   space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000ffff0000,0x00000000ffff0000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 174784K, used 56171K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000faab0000, 0x00000000faab0000)
  object space 174784K, 32% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f36dac38,0x00000000faab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 83966K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 83968K, 99% used [0x00000000eae00000,0x00000000effffb40,0x00000000f0000000)
}
Event: 4040.232 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1800 (full 853):
 PSYoungGen      total 87296K, used 0K [0x00000000faab0000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 87232K, 0% used [0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000faab0000,0x00000000fffe0000)
  from space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000ffff0000)
  to   space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000ffff0000,0x00000000ffff0000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 174784K, used 56171K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000faab0000, 0x00000000faab0000)
  object space 174784K, 32% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f36dac38,0x00000000faab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 83966K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 83968K, 99% used [0x00000000eae00000,0x00000000effffb40,0x00000000f0000000)

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 3250.026 Thread 0x000000000707f800 Uncommon trap -58 fr.pc 0x00000000019ffd28


Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 4035.499 Thread 0x0000000007ae0800 Threw 0x00000000eaea6150 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u10\hotspot\src\share\vm\gc_interface/collectedHeap.inline.hpp:226


Events (10 events):
Event: 4038.120 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedPermanentAllocation done
Event: 4038.120 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedPermanentAllocation
Event: 4038.635 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedPermanentAllocation done
Event: 4038.635 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedPermanentAllocation
Event: 4039.179 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedPermanentAllocation done
Event: 4039.179 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedPermanentAllocation
Event: 4039.686 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedPermanentAllocation done
Event: 4039.687 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedPermanentAllocation
Event: 4040.228 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedPermanentAllocation done
Event: 4040.228 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedPermanentAllocation


Dynamic libraries:
0x0000000140000000 - 0x000000014001e000     C:\Users\Darin\apache-tomcat\bin\Tomcat7.exe
0x0000000077020000 - 0x00000000771cb000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll


VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\Darin\apache-tomcat -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Darin\apache-tomcat -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\Darin\apache-tomcat\endorsed -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Darin\apache-tomcat\temp -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Darin\apache-tomcat\conf\logging.properties -Xmx256m 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ant\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
USERNAME=DARIN-PC$
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7600 

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 6, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, tsc

Memory: 4k page, physical 4192320k(1608396k free), swap 8382744k(5403772k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.6-b04) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_10-b18), built on Nov 28 2012 05:00:40 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Thu Jan 17 17:09:11 2013
elapsed time: 4040 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll. I am not sure if this is the correct way to configure this but it worked for me.

Comment: How did you do that? I'm facing the same issue!

Comment: You could try increasing the memory allocated to the jvm I think it's running out of memory

Comment: If I remember correctly what I did there was modify the environmental variables

Answer (score 3):

**Cause:**

Changing from the client to server directory was not the working for me. The problem for me was the Tomcat was installed under `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0` and the `jvm.dll` file of the JDK was pointing to the `C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.xx\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll`.

> Notice the **C:\Program Files** and the **C:\Program Files(x86)** in the above paths.

As the error message says `%1 is not a valid Win32 application.`, it means the current version of your `jvm.dll` used by tomcat and the installed tomcat versions are different(mix of 32 and 64bit) version. i.e. Tomcat is 32 bit and your JDK is 64 bit and vice-versa.

So use the same version for both JDK and Tomcat. (i.e,) Both should be 32 bit or 64-bit binaries. Where in that case you have a 64 bit os you will find the 64 bit apps installed under `C:\Program Files\` and 32bit apps installed under `C:\Program Files(x86)` directories accordingly.

***Solution:***

- Now open the Tomcat installation folder,
- Go to `bin` directory.
- Run the `Tomcat7w.exe` as administrator.
- Go to the `Java` tab and point your `Java Virtual Machine` path to the JDK version appropriate to you.
- I used `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.xx\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll`
- And Tomcat's path stays the same as is `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0`

As you can notice that the tomcat's and the JDK's path was under the `C:\Program Files`, I had no problem starting the server. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: This worked for me. I was running a 32 bit Tomcat 7 with a 64 bit version of Java 1.8.  Or I was trying to, at least.  Switching tot he 32 bit version of Java 1.8 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found that a JRE version of Java had been installed which changed the Java path under the `tomcat7w.exe` options.

I inspected the folder location and noticed it had been modified:

From:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\bin\server
    "(this is the Java version my Casper JSS server requires)"
```

To:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.051\bin\server
```

Once I fixed that, `net start Tomcat7` and all worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same problem with. After installation and attempted to start Apache Tomcat 7 as service, the tomcat server log (logs/commons-daemon.xx.log) gave: Failed creating java C:\Program Files(x86)\java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll . In fact there is no jre6 install except in Windows/System32 has version 6 java.

It is fixed by specifying the Jvm and updating the service: tomcat7 //US//Tomcat7 --Install="C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\tomcat7.exe" --**Jvm="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll"** --StartMode=jvm --StopMode=jvm --StartClass=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StartParams=start --StopClass=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StopParams=stop

Answer (score 0):

This is not particularly a tomcat problem - same happens on jetty (9.2.2) as well as on tomcat 6.3. As the error says it is rather a memory problem:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005d086c50, pid=7536, tid=8524
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_05-b13) (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x116c50]
```

Increasing memory allocation in eclipse.ini (if server is started from eclipse) can help this partually. In my case I was able to see after increasing another stack trace with infinite recursion.